# Widget set background color

Tags: android, colors, android-linearlayout

How to set RemoteViews LinearLayout's background color programmatically while keeping background shape?

It's easy to set the LinearLayout's background color inside my MainActivity without changing the background's shape:

```
((GradientDrawable) ll_targets.getBackground()).setColor(mColorLinearLayout);
```

[image]

But when I set the background for my Widget, which uses a RemoteViews, the LinearLayout loses its shape and the whole background becomes the color:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(
context.getPackageName(),
R.layout.goals_early_widget);
views.setInt(R.id.ll_widget_goals_early, "setBackgroundColor", Color.RED);
```

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I will do shape of `LinearLayout` as a background `drawable`. Save it as `xml` in your `drawables`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/...." />
         <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip"  android:bottom="0dip" /> <corners
     android:radius="10dp"/> </shape>
```

Then change `LinearLayout` background by calling:

```
yourLinearLayout.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using RemoteViews and not LinearLayout. This is for a Widget.